# concatenating ranges from different sheets not working with sumif in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, stylesheet, google-sheets-api

## background

I'm writing a script in a sheet that relies on ranges from a different sheet. For example this line works perfectly fine using [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en):

```
=sumif(accounting!$D$3:$D$200,A2, accounting!$C$3:$C$200)
```

## problem

when i try to add ranges that consist of subranges (as per instructions [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)):

> You can join multiple ranges into one continuous range using this same
>   punctuation. For example, to combine values from A1-A10 with the
>   values from D1-D10, you can use the following formula to create a
>   range in a continuous column: ={A1:A10; D1:D10}

like so:

```
=sumif({accounting!D3:D6;accounting!D10:D16;accounting!D27:D28},
        A2, 
       {accounting!C3:C6;accounting!C10:C16;accounting!C27:C28})
```

it gives me the following error

> argument must be a range

## note

keep in mind this works

```
=sumif({accounting!D3:D6;accounting!D10:D16;accounting!D27:D28},
        A2,
        accounting!C3:C6)
```

it seems only when i add a range to the third arguments do things blow up.. ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the third argument of `sumif is a range` by default settings of this formula. There is no way to use it with an array.

You may use `sum + filter`

```
=round(sum(filter({accounting!C3:C6;accounting!C10:C16;accounting!C27:C28},
{accounting!D3:D6;accounting!D10:D16;accounting!D27:D28}=A2)), 1)
```

Not sure about Excel, this works only in Google Spreadsheets. Here's [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dt-AkoLauwsdp7ZENgq4s1u8-552GiTX3tQf7gyIIKs/edit#gid=0)

Comment: sorry i'm not much of a sheet expert.. what do you mean by `sum + filter`.. reference? also what does `{..,..,..}=A2` do/mean?

Comment: oh i see.. you are using a completely different approach.. ok i'll read the docs etc and see if it works

Comment: I've added sample sheet with the formula. I don't khow the type of error `no matches found in filter evaluation`, it's usally showed as `#N/A`. Could you share your sample, please?

Comment: don't worry about.. the ranges where messed up